# Rock, Paper, Scissors in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I had a small test in an interview creating a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using an HTML5 DOM. Below the image options that contain 3 images are placeholders to show what I (the user) and the computer randomly picked.

I have a lot of questions about this: First off can the logic be written in jQuery? Event handlers can only do so much. I have made a random # generator in JavaScript before, so I guess use a mixture of jQuery and JS...

Here is a sample of what I have --> http://jsfiddle.net/Tryah85/JxKjk/.I am having trouble specifying classes and ids in jQuery selector `$("#scissors.pick");` is this doable?

First of all, none of the jQuery is working... Here is a snippet... I know the code starts off like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("id-or-class-oreven-html-selector").click( function() {
    });
});
```

I need more direction of basic jQuery event handlers.

Instead of the images I made this fiddle simpler. Basically I want the result of the client to show while also having the browser randomly picking too: thus printing the computers result too. Then finally the result of who won the round would be displayed.

This exercise made me ponder my knowledge of jquery. I thought I had a solid understanding of it, but now I don't know how to solve this, can anyone kindly help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery IS Javascript. It's just a library that makes it easier to do many common operations.

Comment: Also, the code in the fiddle doesn't make sense. You're listening to some element with a className `gesture` to provide the click event, but you don't have it in your html. Also, using `#id.className` type of selectors are redundant. The id has to be unique, so just use `#id`'.

Comment: `if ($("#rock.pick"))` also doesn't make sense. The return value of `$("selector")` is always truthy. Are you trying to test if the element that was clicked on was `#rock`? The way to write that is `if ($(this).is("#rock.pick"))`

Comment: here is something I have made in 5 min just for the kick of it... have fun http://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/Jwsnu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed quite a bit, maybe this helps

all your if statements may be reduced drastically, although still not very nice like

```
$("#yourMove .move").html($("h2", $(this).clone()))
                    .addClass($(this).attr('data-pick'));
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JxKjk/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#scissors.pick"); is this doable?
```

No, its not doable, If you have a unique id, just use,

```
$("#scissors")
```

As Evan Trimboli suggested in the comments,

> You're listening to some element with a className gesture to provide
>   the click event, but you don't have it in your html. Also, using
>   id.className type of selectors are redundant. The id has to be unique, so just use #id.

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JxKjk/1/)**, that shows how you determine the player's move, similarly you can pick randomly, the pc's move and then decide who won.

A click on any id should be used as,

```
$("#rock").click(function(){
    $("#yourMove").text("Your Move: Rock");
});
```

Looking for a shorter code? Do it in a single line.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JxKjk/3/)**

```
  $("#rock, #paper, #scissors").click(function(){
        $("#yourMove").text("Your Move: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```